# Скрытие value по условию при начальном входе в проект

Tags: jquery

Когда заходим на ***web*** проект то в списке  `presentId` всегда показывает УСТНОЕ.

Если выбрать `presentId value="2">ПИСЬМЕННОЕ` и потом снова выбрать УСТНОЕ то УСЛОВИЕ СРАБАТЫВАЕТ.

Необходимо, чтобы когда было вначале выбрано `presentId value="1">УСТНОЕ` то в `type` нужно скрыть `value="2">Заявление`.

```js
function presentIdchange() {

  if ($('#presentId').val() == '1') {
    $("#type").empty();
    //alert("[f[]]");
    $("#type").append($('<option value="0"></option>'));
    $("#type").append($('<option value="1">Жалоба</option>'));
    $("#type").append($('<option value="3">Консультация</option>'));
    $("#type").append($('<option value="4">Предложение</option>')

    }
    else {
      $("#type").empty();

      $("#type").append($('<option value="0"></option>'));
      $("#type").append($('<option value="1">Жалоба</option>'));
      $("#type").append($('<option value="2">Заявление</option>'));
      $("#type").append($('<option value="3">Консультация</option>'));
      $("#type").append($('<option value="4">Предложение</option>'));
    }

  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="presentId" name="presentId" onclick="changepresentId()" onchange="presentIdchange()">
  <option value="1">УСТНОЕ</option>
  <option value="2">ПИСЬМЕННОЕ</option>
</select>
…
<select id="type" name="typeId" onchange="document.getElementById('typeWarning').hidden = true;">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="1">Жалоба</option>
  <option value="2">Заявление</option>
  <option value="3">Консультация</option>
  <option value="4">Предложение</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Так?

```js
$('#s1').bind('change', function(){
  var s1 = $(this).val();
  if(s1==2) {
    $('#s2 option[value="2"]').hide();
  } else {
    $('#s2 option[value="2"]').show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!----------------------------------->
<select id="s1">
  <option value="1" selected>Устное</option>
  <option value="2">Писменное</option>
</select>

<select id="s2">
  <option style="display:none;" selected></option>
  <option value="1">Жалоба</option>
  <option value="2">Заявление</option>
  <option value="3">Консультация</option>
  <option value="4">Предложение</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Не реагирует как надо

Comment: @dmr, сорян, забыл "обратное действие", обновил ответ.